Transient state for simple case of two resistors in DC circuit
The scenario: DC circuit with EMF of 12V and 2 resistors: 2 ohm and 4 ohm.
Can someone give an explanation of what is going in this circuit until it gets to steady state current?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_crwFuPht4 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2AXv49dDQJw

You have to specify how the resistors are connected.

Let's say in series
